# Prove that this function is a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, where $\Omega$ is an uncountable set, and $\mathcal F := \{A \subset \Omega: A \text{ is countable or }A^c \text{ is countable}\}$.
Prove that $\mu: \mathcal F \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ defined as:
$$\mu (A) = 
\ \begin{cases} 
      0 & ,A \text{ is countable} \\   
      1 & ,A^c \text{ is countable} 
   \end{cases}
\
$$
is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$.

I have already shown that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$.

Also, by taking an arbitrary sequence $Z_1, Z_2, ... \in \mathcal F$ (with $Z_i \cap Z_j = \varnothing$), I have shown that $\mu (\bigcup\limits^{}_{n\geq1}Z_n) = 1$ because $(\bigcup\limits^{}_{n\geq1}Z_n)^c$ is countable. However, I don't know how to get $\sum_{n\geq1}\mu(Z_n) = 1$ to conclude that $\mu$ is a measure (doesn't seem possible to me).

Any idea?

Comment: What if the $Z_n$ are countable? What would be the measure of their union?

Comment: @Joe The measure of the union would be 0 as well.

Comment: I agree, but that doesn’t seem to match what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion:

If the $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint and If $\bigcup_nA_n$ is countable, then all the $A_n$ are countable and $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all $n$. So no problem here

If  the $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint and   $\bigcup_nA_n$ is uncountable, then  and at least one of the sets  $A_n$ must be uncountable. The question is, can there be more than one uncountable sets $A_n$? if that is answer is yes, then $\mu$ is it is define is not a measure. Now, If $A_n$ and $A_n'$ disjoint and $A_n$ is uncountable, then, as $A_{n'}\subset\Omega\setminus A_n$, it must be that $A_{n'}$ is at most coutbable.

Answer (score 1):

The measure of a countable union $U$ of $Z_n$ is $0$ if $U$ is countable, in which case all of the $Z_n$ are countable, or $1$ if $U$ is uncountable (in which case) at least one of the $Z_n$ is uncountable. Either way, the addition formula works.